# AssertionError: ZeroDivisionError not raised by fun

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function called `division`. After an exception is raised in the `try` block, it's getting caught by `except` block, so I am getting an `AssertionError` while testing the `except` block. I need to test the `except` block to get code coverage to 100%, and I need to test the caught exception. How can I test the `except` block?

```
def division(a,b):
    try:
       print(a/b)
    except ZeroDivisionError as ze:
       print(ze)

class TestDivision(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_division(self):

       self.assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError, division, 1, 0)
```

Comment: show us the traceback maybe?

Comment: if you just test the `try` block normally then it works, what is your issue?

Comment: You are handling the exception so it is never actually raised to test.

Answer (score 1):

The function in question is  **NON TESTABLE**.

It neither `returns` a value nor `changes some object`.

The only thing it will return is an exception which is other than '`ZeroDivisionError`', which is not possible for the function logic.

So it is not possible to test the function without changing the function code itself and making it '**TESTABLE**'.

Answer (score 1):

Because the function catch the ZeroDivisionError.
When a / b raised the ZeroDivisionError, the code will print ez and return None.Remove the 'except ZeroDivisionError' and the test will pass.