# How to tell whether a function has been tested sufficiently in Python with unittest?

Tags: python, function, unit-testing

Suppose we have a function which returns specificity (spec):

**filename: data.py**

```
def spec(TN, FP):
    try:
        spec = TN / (TN + FP)
        return spec

    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return float("nan")
```

I'm testing this with the following:

```
import unittest

class TestSpec(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_spec(self):
        result = data.spec(1, 2)
        self.assertEqual(result, 1/3)
```

How do I know if this is a complete test? Because I've only used two inputs (and expect the result 1/3 with these inputs). How do I know whether to test it with e.g. negative values? Slightly confused on the extent it would be beneficial to test a function other than just with two inputs in this case. What's best practice?

Comment: there a module called coverage, that tells you the percentage of the code tests, and highlight the lines of code that hasn't been tested yet

Comment: Test coverage reporting, mutation testing, "glass box" testing (i.e. you wrote the code so you *know* it's not fully covered by that test).

Comment: A code coverage tool will tell you you didn’t cover the exception condition, which actually has an error casting that text to a float.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen thank you. Is it possible to test this exception condition? Because I'm reading mixed things about whether you can or can't. E.g. this thread implies not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225131/assertionerror-zerodivisionerror-not-raised-by-fun

Comment: That question’s answer is due to the function not returning anything. Technically that function could be tested by capturing stdout.  Your function returns something, but the exception condition returns code that is currently a syntax error.

Comment: I've fixed my code so that now it doesn't return a syntax error. Do you have any suggestions on what I should investigate to test the exception bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a code coverage tool (such as [Coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.3/) to see what lines of code are tested by a test.

Testing for `nan` is tricky, since `float('nan') == float('nan')` returns `False`.

Below is shown how to test for `nan` as well as simply testing for the `ZeroDivisionError` exception directly:

```
import unittest
import math

def spec1(TN, FP):
    try:
        spec = TN / (TN + FP)
        return spec
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return float("nan")

def spec2(TN, FP):
    spec = TN / (TN + FP)
    return spec

class TestSpec(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_spec1_good_values(self):
        result = spec1(1, 2)
        self.assertEqual(result, 1/3)

    def test_spec1_nan(self):
        result = spec1(1,-1)
        self.assertTrue(math.isnan(result))

    def test_spec2_good_values(self):
        result = spec2(1, 2)
        self.assertEqual(result, 1/3)

    def test_spec2_exception(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError):
            spec2(1,-1)
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```